# Android: Time.setToNow()- Minute value not formatted correctly?

Tags: android, time, format

In the following code In my `Android` application I am sdisplaying the time as the `current time` like so:

```
 String timeToDisplay;
 Time time = new Time();
    time.setToNow();
    timeToDisplay = time.hour + ":" + time.minute + ":"
    + time.second;
```

This is working as intended but the output `minute format` is not exactly what I want.

I want to have e.g.:

```
21:05:45
```

But I am getting:

```
21:5:45
```

i.e. the `zero` is missing from the minute.

How can I ensure that the zero is shown in the `time.minute` if the minute is under 10 past the hour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are getting the int value of `minute` it wont really give you the 0 before it but you can still format your string and append **"0"** before the `time.minute`

**sample:**

```
timeToDisplay = time.hour + ":" + (time.minute < 10 ? "0"+time.minute : time.minute) + ":"
```